# Delete words in a line using grep or sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I want to delete three words with a special character on a line such as

Input:

```
\cf4 \cb6 1749,1789 \cb3 \
```

Output:

```
1749,1789
```

I have tried a couple sed and grep statements but so far none have worked, mainly due to the character `\`.

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
sed -i 's/ [.\c ] //g' inputfile.ext >output file.ext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk accepts a regex Field Separator (in this case, comma or space):

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' '$0 = $3 "." $4' <<< '\cf4 \cb6 1749,1789 \cb3 \'
1749.1789
```

- `-F'[ ,]'` - Use a single character from the set `space/comma` as Field Separator
- `$0 = $3 "." $4` - If we can set the entire line `$0` to Field 3 `$4` followed by a literal period `"."` followed by Field 4 `$4`, do the default behavior (print entire line)

Replace `<<< 'input'` with `file` if every line of that file has the same delimeters (spaces/comma) and number of fields. If your input file is more complex than the sample you shared, please edit your question to show actual input.

Comment: could you please be so kind as to explain to me what exactly you did  there as i am struggling to understand that command. would that work on a file that has multiple lines ?

Comment: Thank you very much! The source consists of n lines of the same style so I would say it is not complex

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is a special meta-character that confuses bash.

We treat it like any other meta-character, by escaping it, with--you guessed it--a backslash!

But first, we need to grep this pattern out of our file

```
grep '\\... \\... [0-9]+,[0-9]+ \\... \\' our_file # Close enough!
```

Now, just sed out those pesky backslashes

```
| sed -e 's/\\//g' # Don't forget the g, otherwise it'll only strip out 1 backlash
```

Now, finally, sed out the clusters of 2 alpha followed by a number and a space!

```
 | sed -e 's/[a-z][a-z][0-9] //g'
```

And, finally....

```
grep '\\... \\... [0-9]+,[0-9]+ \\... \\' our_file | sed -e 's/\\//g' | sed -e 's/[a-z][a-z][0-9] //g'
```

Output:

> 1749,1789

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I have been looking everywhere for an actual explanation (yes I know there are loads of docs and examples widely available, but I have struggled with most of them trying to understand the syntax) !

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are having trouble because you have backslashes in input and can't figure out how to get backslashes into your regex. Since backslashes are escape characters to shell and regex you end up having to type four backslashes to get one into your regex.

Ben Van Camp already posted an answer that uses single quotes to make the escaping a little easier; however I shall now post an answer that simply avoids the problem altogether.

```
grep -o '[0-9]*,[0-9]*' | tr , .
```

Locks on to the comma and selects the digits on either side and outputs the number. Alternately if comma is not guaranteed we can do it this way:

```
egrep -o ' [0-9,]*|^[0-9,]*' | tr , . | tr -d ' '
```

Both of these assume there's only one usable number per line.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ awk '{sub(/,/,".",$3); print $3}' file
1749.1789

$ sed 's/\([^ ]* \)\{2\}\([^ ]*\).*/\2/; s/,/./' file
1749.1789
```

Comment: Please add some comments to explain how your code answers the question in order to improve this answer.

Comment: @EricHauenstein When the automated tool flags a code-only answer as **possibly** low quality if you know the domain then read the answer and make an informed decision whether it requires documentation or not and if it does **then** post a useful comment. If you don't know the domain, as apparently is the case here, then just move along as rubber-stamping the tools flag is just wasting everyone's time, including yours, and cluttering up the site.

Comment: I disagree.  It is well-established that code-only answers are generally improved by commentary explaining how and why they work, and a reviewer does not need domain knowledge to determine whether comments are present.

Comment: You are welcome to disagree of course but you are totally wrong and it is certainly not "well established". Someone who doesn't understand an absolutely basic script will learn far more from a cursory glance at the man pages than being spoon fed just why this one script works and cluttering up the site with every answer providing descriptions of the fundamentals for every tool used in every answer would be ludicrous.

Comment: If a reviewer didn't need domain knowledge to determine whether comments are present or not and them being missing DID indicate a problem then the tool would itself comment on code-only answers rather than flagging it as **possibly** low quality for people **with domain knowledge** to decide how to handle the answer. You'll notice that the tool doesn't flag answers that have lengthy, complicated code with text that doesn't actually explain the code - if you want to do something useful with your spare time then find those answers and comment on them.

Comment: This answer is being discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386830/7296893). I tend to side with Eric here, while it's not required comments could improve the answer, especially noting [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856735/grep-sed-delete-words-in-line/56869381#comment100264276_56857042) by the OP. Of course, your answer shouldn't be deleted, but something about _giving a man a fish vs teaching him how to fish_ seems applicable here. Also note: [he flagged _looks ok_](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23428960)

Comment: @ErikA [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856735/grep-sed-delete-words-in-line/56869381#comment100264276_56857042) from the OP is about trying to understand the convoluted logic needed to use sed+grep to solve this, not about understanding the trivial scripts I posted. I **am** teaching a man to fish here - even assuming the OP can't figure it out at a glance (which people with ANY awk or sed experience can), I'm teaching the OP how to look up trivial constructs so that when she is working later and comes across some code she doesn't understand she knows how to handle it.

Comment: Actually it is all good ! There’s no more need of further explaination on this topic from my side it’s all working !

Comment: @AlanDeMoin Questions/answers here are not meant to be just for the questioners benefit, they are expected to help future visitors. While you yourself may not need further explanation, future visitors might.

Comment: @canon it's definitely *principled* - the answer is absolutely fine as-is and wouldn't be getting any downvotes if not for that meta post. It's actually getting upvotes but just more downvotes are dragging it down overall.

Comment: Personally, I don't have the domain experience to discern whether the code has merit on its own; so, I haven't voted.

Comment: Makes sense. The guy who started this chain of comments [is now better informed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386830/is-domain-knowledge-required-to-determine-whether-code-snippets-should-be-commen#comment709048_386831) and won't be commenting on code-only answers in domains he doesn't understand any more either so something positive did come out of this.

Comment: @canon: I believe most SO regulars have at least a passing familiarity with `awk` and `sed`. Personally I'm confused by the use of a semicolon in the `sed` command, and definitely think the answer would benefit from som further explanation. But this is why I tend to avoid [bash], it's too 'gate-keepey' for me.

Comment: @AkselA a semi-colon separates statements. It's one of the 2 common statement separator used in all shells and all shell commands, the other being a newline.

Comment: @AkselA An answer to a specific problem does not require to explain the whole syntax of the language (again and again). If you don't know what the semicolon does, either google it, guess it or just post a comment below the answer and ask for clarification. But generally I agree that a few sentences of explanation would make this great answer even better

Comment: @AkselA put it on next year's SO Developer Survey and let's find out.